# HTML/CSS/JS: Rollover-Effect for navigation-menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got another CSS/JS question: I want to make a navigation menu, where there is at the beginning a div with just a text in it. If I hover with the mouse on it, there should appear a background from the left to the right.

Is this only possible with JS (so if hover, an interval gets startet which moves the background behind the text) or are there any other possibilities?

I hope you understood what I tried to say ...

Thanks for help!

Flo

EDIT: It's something moving just like this navigation here: http://iipvapi.com/, but only a simple background from the left to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `:hover` [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes). This will not provide animation functionality though. It will just apply the style or not based on whether you are hovering.

You could do it with pure JavaScript, but it would be a little awkward if you want animation.

You could do it with JavaScript using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which provides [animation functionality](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) and is easy to use. You probably want the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function, as it sounds like a bit more of a custom solution than functions such as [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) would provide.

Comment: Hm, I could probably solve it by using show(), because I do want a background for a text, which is quite long, but not very high, and this might look good... thanks for the idea! :)